# JInternalFrame acts weird when windows theme changed?

Tags: java, swing, windows-xp, jframe, look-and-feel

This is my sample code. I am trying to embed a `JInternalFrame` without titlebar display into a `JFrame`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

class A{

public void doThis(){
    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    fr.setSize(300,300);
    JInternalFrame f = new JInternalFrame();
    f.setSize(200,200);
    BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI) f.getUI();
    ui.setNorthPane(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    fr.add(f);
    fr.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MainA{

 public static void main(String a[]){
    A obj = new A();
    obj.doThis();
 }
}
```

The code works fine and displays a `JInternalFrame` within a `JFrame` without titlebar as per the requirement as shown below.

[image: Before Theme Change]

I still have this UI running and at the same time when I try to change my XP theme (via Properties>>Appearance>>Theme), the UI automatically repaints itself to show the `JInternalFrame` with a titlebar again as shown below.

[image: After Theme Change]

I just can't understand this bizarre behavior. I have no clue if this is an issue with Java Swing or if it is something related to the OS. Please help me with this!

Why is the UI repainting upon theme change with an enabled titlebar when I explicitly code for the titleBar to be set as null?

PS: OS used is Windows XP and I am not sure if the same behavior is observed in Linux or other versions of Windows

Comment: Tips: 1) *"java swings"*  No, that is "Java Swing"  (note upper case letters and number of 's' characters). 2) *"..not sure if the same behavior is observed in ... other versions of Windows"* I could have told you if it was the same in Windows 7 if you'd posted an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: @Andrew I was running the previous code snippet as a script on groovy console. So if it is according to java that you are asking, I've made the edits for the same.

Answer (score 2):

'do' is a keyword in Java, so that code does not compile for me.  This code does.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

class A{

    public void doIt(){
        JFrame fr = new JFrame();
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setSize(300,300);
        JInternalFrame f = new JInternalFrame();
        f.setSize(200,200);
        fr.add(f);
        BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI) f.getUI();
        ui.setNorthPane(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

 public static void main(String a[]){
    A obj = new A();
    obj.doIt();
 }
}
```

Some notes/questions:

1. Swing GUIs should be constructed & altered on the EDT.
2. Why does the code add a `JInternalFrame` directly to anything other than a `JDesktopPane`?
3. There are slight issues with sizing of the `JInternalFrame` when changing themes.  I suspect it has to do with the lack of `validate()`/`pack()` in the code.  Since that was not the question, I could not be bothered investigating it further.

---

### Results

I got a 'null result' here using Windows 7.  The title bar of the `JInternalFrame` did not re-appear at any time when changing through (in order):

1. Forbidden Planet (a custom, simple theme)
2. Windows 7 (Aero)
3. Architecture (Aero)
4. Windows 7 Basic (Basic & High Contrast)
5. Windows Classic (Basic & High Contrast)
6. Forbidden Planet